# Can Spark store part of a single RDD partition in memory and part on disk?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Per the title: can Spark store part of a single RDD/Dataset/DataFrame partition in memory and part on disk? In other words assuming the persistence level supports it, if a partition is too large to store in memory can it be partly held in memory and partly on disk?

My use case is that I that I want to write out very large Parquet files, and Spark's write behavior is to write out a file for each partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible in spark. The memory and disk options use the partition as the smallest data division.
According to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence), if the MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level is used, partitions that do not fit memory are saved on the disk.

> MEMORY_AND_DISK   Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If
>   the RDD does not fit in memory, store the partitions that don't fit on
>   disk, and read them from there when they're needed.

MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER has a similar behavior but Store RDD as serialized Java objects (one byte array per partition)

Perhaps you have some way to reduce the size of the partition instead. I think that could help.